# When using Spark with HDFS, which way is correct for HDFS setup?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

1. set Spark driver node as *HDFS* master node and Spark worker nodes as *HDFS* slave nodes.

or

2. use only the Spark worker nodes to set up a *HDFS* cluster. The *HDFS* master node is contained in those worker nodes

p.s: I know *HDFS* and Spark are separate parts but there can be a preferred way of testing application performance on Spark when given a limited number of nodes? So, essentially, should we avoid I/O cost on the Spark driver node?

Answer (score 0):

HDFS cluster *should* be accessible from driver node, so the first option makes more sense.

Setup for performance testing depends mainly on the expected application workload, memory available on nodes and other parameters, but if the part of the application running on the driver doesn't do any heave processing it might make sense to put the name node there.

Comment: so in your saying "HDFS cluster should be accessible from driver node", if in the second option, the driver node can ssh to the nodes in the seperate HDFS cluster, can we say in this case the driver node can access the HDFS cluster? Thus, in the spark-submit command line, I can write something like "bin/spark-submit --class foo --master spark://spark-mster:7077 boo.jar hdfs://seperate-hdfs-master:9000/data/file. (if we run a foo class in an application called boo and it needs a hdfs file path as its program argument)

Comment: does the spark master node and hdfs master node have to be the same?